# Data Structure - Minimum time to copy a file into all Nodes

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I have a below problem statement and it seems like it can be solved using dynamic programming (recurrence relation) but not able to solve it.

**Problem statement:** - There are N identical nodes(identical computer with equal resources). Each node connected to other n-1 nodes. One of the node contains a file f. This files needs to be copied on the remaining machines (n-1) minimizing total time to copy. Copying of file is done by invoking an api `void copyFile(Node source, Node destination)`.

Please note that copying from same source to multiple destination can also be achieved but may cause a bit delay as resources of the source machine would be shared. Below are the given benchmark data depicting the same.

| Number of destination to copy from single source | time taken (in second) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 |
| 2 | t2 |
| 3 | t3 |
| . | .. |
| k | tk |

1<=N<=100

1<=k<N

tp<tq if p < q

---

```
Example 1:
Input

N = 8, k = 4
time = [10, 16, 20, 23]

Output - 20+10 = 30 sec.

Explanation - Assume Node n1 already was having the file.
In the first cycle, n2,n3 and n4 starts copying (i.e. invoke `copyFile` on those node) from same source node n1.
And then once 4 of the nodes (n1-4) have file, in then next cycle remaining all 4 nodes can start copying to all remaining nodes disjointly (i.e. one-one copying).
Therefore in the first cycle it took 20 sec and in next cycle 10 sec, so total 30 sec.
```

Comment: From your example I gather that all nodes are connected directly to the remaining `n-1` nodes, but you haven't stated that explicitly. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. I will update in case it is not inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Two things we care in this problem are: a) how many computers have the file and b) when. Given this pair of numbers, we can reject all scenarios achieving the same number in longer time. So, the algorithm

Create an array of `N` times it takes to achieve `i` computers having the file (sources). We have one source at t=0 from the start:

| 0 | inf | inf | inf | inf | inf | inf | inf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

At this point, we can copy the file to 1,2,...k computers, adding 10, 16, ... time[k-1] to the time it takes:

| 0 | 10 | 16 | 20 | 23 | inf | inf | inf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Now, we know that earliest it takes to achieve two sources is 10 seconds. Now, we can expand it to 2, 4, ...2k sources in 10, 16, ... time[k-1] seconds. E.g., 8 computers below is achieved by copying to 3 computers from each of two sources, starting at 10 seconds (thus, 10+20).

If we already know a better way to achieve one of these states, we simply ignore it. For example, we can get 4 computers by copying to 3 computers from 1 source, or by copying to 2 computers from each of 2 sources (10+10s). There is no difference in this case, but if copying to 3 computers cost 19 or 21 seconds, you'd see the difference.

| 0 | 10 | 16 | 20 | 23 | 26 | inf | 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

A small optimization: since we're at least doubling the number of copies at each step, it is enough to expand only states up to N/2 - it will cover all possible ways to get N copies already.

```py
# setup
N=8
time = [10, 16, 20, 23]

# initialize the array: 1 computer at 0 seconds, infinity for all others (we'll expand onto these states later)
states = [float('inf')] * N
states[0] = 0

# due to optimization, we only expand states up to N/2 sources
for i in range((N+1) // 2):
    # this variable is here is to distinguish between 0-based index and 1-based number of sources
    num_sources = i+1
    # range(num_sources*2, N+1, num_sources): generate multiples of num_sources, up to N+1
    # zip(..., time) - pair projected number of sources with time it takes to copy 
    for next_state, seconds in zip(range(num_sources*2, N+1, num_sources), time):
        # the recurrent formula explained above
        states[next_state-1] = min(states[next_state-1], states[i] + seconds)

print(states[-1])
```

To recover sequence leading to `N` sources, go in reverse. Start from N, then for `i \in 1..k` check if time to achieve `N / (i+1)` is different by exactly the corresponding element of `time`; repeat until reached 1 source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Too concise to understand for me as I am not aware of python syntax. Can you please brief this a bit. Also how to store the sequence of in which set of computers starts copying. example - cycle 1 - n1->n2,n1->n3 and n1->n4, cycle 2 - n1->n5, n2->n6, n3->n7 and n4->n8.